# Laravel - pass data to blade

Tags: laravel, href

I have next line

```
 <h5><a href="{{ url('rent', $brands->brand_name.'-'.$cars->model.'-'.$cars->transmiter ) }}" 
 target="_blank">{{$brands->brand_name}}/{{$cars->model}}</a></h5>
```

and I got url when press link like this

http://localhost/mySite/rent/Citroen-C4-manual

How to create new blade page with this data from url (Citroen-C4-manual). I don't now how to get this data because I don't have id and i don't need to see id in url?

I use in routes.php

```
 Route::resource('rent', 'myController');
```

and in myController i have

```
class myControllerextends Controller{
  public function index(){
     return view('data.car');
  }

  public function show($id){
   view('data.car');
  }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `slug` column to a table. Since you're using `Route::resource`, your `show()` method should look like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    // Search data by slug.
    Model::where('slug', $id)->first();
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the packages which will add slugs related features to your app.